# Should I learn C++ based on new or old standard (specification)?

Tags: c++, c++11

OK, I am considering of getting into c++ development in coming months (there is no set date).  I am vaguely familiar with the language (primarily C), as well as some basics of OO, MI, templates, exceptions, patterns, used STL. And now I am at the point in time where I would like to master the language in depth. And the natural question is whether I should
start with current **C++03** or **C++0x** standard.

Please suggest what the best way to go from a user to guru, given that new standard is almost here, and likely to remain for many years to come.

Thanks

Comment: What do you hope to gain by learning C++?

If you're interested in language design, C++0X would be more interesting. If you want to do professional development, however, you should definitely stick to the C++03 standard.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My recommendation is to start out in the middle. Start with C++03, but check the features and C++0x libs that some compilers are already offering each so often. As of now, C++03 is THE standard (not only formally, but most code you will find will be strictly C++03).

Now, if you intend on learning go for the best: start quickly with STL basics and jump into Boost libraries right away. Learn templates the whole way, read on metaprogramming. Modern C++03 usage will get you right on track for C++0x.

Answer (score 6):

Learn the older standard C++03.  C++0X is still a couple years away (at least) from even being ratified as a standard.  Once it's standardized, it'll take time before *any* conforming implementations appear that support all of its features, and it'll take an even *longer* time before C++0X implementations become significantly popular and oft-used.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, learn C++03 is more practical. If you don't mind learning new features but can use partial for several years, C++0x is better. Good news is g++ new version and vc++2010 already implemented parts of new c++0x features.

Answer (score 1):

Learning the new C++0x features is a great way to learn more about C++03 in depth because you see how C++03 works, the problems with it, and what c++0x proposes to do to solve those problems.

I had this experience recently learning about the new rvalue references and move semantics. In C++03 there's a lot of unnecessary temporary creation and copying in expressions, learning about why c++03 has this problem and how C++0x solves this problem was pretty enlightening and informed my current C++ development.

Answer (score 1):

It's going to be a few years before C++0x compilers are common. So at the moment, you don't have much choice. Learn C++03, and then you can learn the new stuff separately, when the time comes. The fundamental differences aren't that great. 0x is mostly a matter of new features being bolted on, and existing features being generalized and streamlined. Knowledge of C++03 will still be applicable.